# Multi-field terms aggregation approach

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index with documents like the following:

```
[
    {
        "name": "Marco",
        "city_id": 45,
        "city": "Rome"
    },
    {
        "name": "John",
        "city_id": 46,
        "city": "London"
    },
    {
        "name": "Ann",
        "city_id": 47,
        "city": "New York"
    },
    ...
]
```

and an aggregation:

```
"aggs": {
    "city": {
        "terms": {
            "field": "city"
        }
    }
}
```

That gives me a response like this:

```
{
    "aggregations": {    
        "city": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 694,
            "buckets": [
                {
                    "key": "Rome",
                    "doc_count": 15126
                },
                {
                    "key": "London",
                    "doc_count": 11395
                },
                {
                    "key": "New York",
                    "doc_count": 14836
                },
                ...
          ]
        },
        ...
    }
}
```

My problem is that I need to have the `city_id` on my aggregation result as well. I have been reading [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#_multi_field_terms_aggregation) that I can't have multi-field terms aggregations, but I don't need to aggregate by two fields but simply return another field that will be always the same for each term field (basically a city/city_id pair). What would be the best way to achieve that without losing performance?

I can create a field named `city_with_id` with values like `"Rome;45"`, `"London;46"`, etc and make the aggregation by this field. For me it would work because I can simply split the results on my backend and get the the ID I need, but is it the best approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach would be to use [top_hits](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html) and use source filtering to return only the `city_id` as show in the example below. 
I don't think this would be prohibitively less performant
You could try it on your indexes to see the impact before trying out the approach of `city_name_id` field specified in OP.

Example:

```
    post <index>/_search
    {
        "size" : 0,
        "aggs": {
            "city": {
                "terms": {
                    "field": "city"
                },
                "aggs" : {
                    "id" : {
                        "top_hits" : {
                            "_source": {
                                "include": [
                                    "city_id"
                                ]
                            },
                            "size" : 1
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Results:

```
 {
               "key": "London",
               "doc_count": 2,
               "id": {
                  "hits": {
                     "total": 2,
                     "max_score": 1,
                     "hits": [
                        {
                           "_index": "country",
                           "_type": "city",
                           "_id": "2",
                           "_score": 1,
                           "_source": {
                              "city_id": 46
                           }
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               }
            },
            {
               "key": "New York",
               "doc_count": 1,
               "id": {
                  "hits": {
                     "total": 1,
                     "max_score": 1,
                     "hits": [
                        {
                           "_index": "country",
                           "_type": "city",
                           "_id": "3",
                           "_score": 1,
                           "_source": {
                              "city_id": 47
                           }
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               }
            },
            {
               "key": "Rome",
               "doc_count": 1,
               "id": {
                  "hits": {
                     "total": 1,
                     "max_score": 1,
                     "hits": [
                        {
                           "_index": "country",
                           "_type": "city",
                           "_id": "1",
                           "_score": 1,
                           "_source": {
                              "city_id": 45
                           }
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               }
            }
```

Comment: It worked! Actually I've lost a considerable amount of time using this approach because my example was just illustrative - in the real scenario I have lots of fields that I needed to apply the nested aggregation and the result was not acceptable. Anyway, it worked, I will accept your answer. Thank you very much!